# Inconsistency when creating a Date from milis

Tags: java, date

I'm having an strange problem when trying to create a java.util.Date object from a long value representing another one but in milis, In my server I'm sending the following value 1337621330502 wich represents : a java.sql.Timestamp 2012-05-21 12:28:50.502. Now in a client I'm parsing some data and retreiving that date from a JSONObject, and then creating a date like this:

```
workItem.setActivityStartDate(new Date(workItemJson.getLong("activityStartDate")));
```

Where `workItemJson.getLong("activityStartDate")`, returns 1337621330502, however the date created adds 1 hour to the original value, Mon May 21 13:28:50 America/New_York 2012.
Why is happening this? Date format or something similar?. Isn't timeInMilis the same value regarding the timeZone or any other factor that could affect the time?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Server doesn't have daylight savings and your computer does have daylight savings, possibly?

Answer (score 2):

The server and client are probably running in different locales, check [`Locale.getDefault()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getDefault%28%29) to see the difference.